# On the properness of the graph of a convex function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, convex-geometry, convexity

Let $f : \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth and convex function. Let us assume that $\Gamma_f = \mathrm{graph}(f) $ is a complete hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then I know that $\Gamma_f$ must be **properly** embedded.

I can prove this simple fact with an argument by contradiction, but I was wondering if there is a more direct and elegant proof.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "properly embedded"?

Comment: I mean that the inclusion $i : \Gamma_f \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a proper function. Namely, given a compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, the preimage $i^{-1}(K) = K \cap \Gamma_f$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly elementary proof is as follows (I assume you are using the convention that $f$ convex means $\Omega$ is convex and $f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$).  For $x,y\in \Omega$ let $[x,y]\subset \Omega$ be the segment connecting them.

Idea, if $p=(x,f(x)),q=(y,f(y))\in \Gamma_f$, then one has
$$
d(p,q)\leq \int_0^1 \sqrt{|x-y|^2+|x-y|^2 |f'(tx+(1-t)y)|^2} dt
$$
where here $d(p,q)$ is the intrinsic distance in $\Gamma_f$. 
That is,
$$
d(p,q)\leq |x-y| \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+ |f'(tx+(1-t)y)|^2} dt
$$
Using $\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ gives
$$
d(p,q) \leq |x-y| \int_0^1 1+ |f'(tx+(1-t)y)| dt
$$
and so
$$
d(p,q) \leq |x-y|(1+f(x)+f(y)-2\min_{z\in [x,y]} f(z)).
$$
Where this last estimate using the fact that $f|_{[x,y]}$ is convex.

It follows, that if $d(p,p_i)\to \infty$ for a sequence $p_i=(y_i, f(y_i))$, then either $y_i\to \infty$ or $f(y_i)\to \infty$ and so one concludes $\Gamma_f$ is proper as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** New answer, after the clarification on properness.

Let $K$ be a compact subset of  $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, i.e. let $K$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The graph $\Gamma_f$ is complete in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ if and only if it is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Hence $K \cap \Gamma_f$ is closed (because both are closed) and bounded (because at least one is bounded), hence compact.

Comment: By "complete" I mean as submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. For instance consider the graph of the function $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$. The graph of this function can be viewed as a complete submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but is not a closed subset. And indeed is not properly embedded.

Comment: Oh, I see! You meant complete w.r.t. its own geodesic distance, not in the metric of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: exactly :)  Sorry, I was a bit sketchy..

Answer (score 0):

If $\Omega$ has a boundary, then smoothness and convexity are enough to ensure properness over its interior, but I think you need bounded first derivative for properness over its boundary: e.g. $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^+ \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f = x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! But in your counterexample the graph is not a complete hypersurface (curve) of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It is a closed subset of a metric space, hence it is (Cauchy) complete. Did you mean to use some other notion of completeness?

Comment: Btw I just saw your comment above. I had a different notion of proper in mind, namely transversality at the boundary (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361794/definitions-of-a-proper-embedding)). Ignore my answer then.